# VB Expression in SSRS Causing Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, t-sql, reporting-services

I am working on an expression for SSRS to change background cell colours. I keep getting an error On the second IIF statement and I have no idea why, maybe someone can spot an error i made?

This was the original expression i made... Which worked great,

```
=IIF((Fields!DriveLetter.Value = "F:" OR Fields!DriveLetter.Value = "T:") AND (Fields!FileType.Value = "MDF" OR Fields!FileType.Value = "NDF"), "Lime",
IIF((Fields!DriveLetter.Value = "G:" OR Fields!DriveLetter.Value = "U:") AND (Fields!FileType.Value = "LDF"), "Lime", "Tomato") )
```

I added one more IIF statement with added logic and that caused the error. I kept playing with it but couldnt get the error to go.

```
=IIF((Fields!DriveLetter.Value = "F:" OR Fields!DriveLetter.Value = "T:") AND (Fields!FileType.Value = "MDF" OR Fields!FileType.Value = "NDF"), "Green",
 IIF(Fields!DriveLetter.Value = "G:" OR Fields!DriveLetter.Value = "U:") AND (Fields!FileType.Value = "LDF"), "Green",
 IIF(Fields!DriveLetter.Value = "C:") AND (Fields!Database_Name.Value = "master" OR Fields!Database_Name.Value = "model" OR Fields!Database_Name.Value = "msdb" 
                                                                                 OR Fields!Database_Name.Value = "tempdb"), "Lime", "Red" )
```

Thanks.

Comment: your hooks are all messed up. Sort it out first

Comment: IIF(((Fields!DriveLetter.Value = "F:" OR Fields!DriveLetter.Value = "T:") AND (Fields!FileType.Value = "MDF" OR Fields!FileType.Value = "NDF")), "Green",
 IIF(((Fields!DriveLetter.Value = "G:" OR Fields!DriveLetter.Value = "U:") AND (Fields!FileType.Value = "LDF")), "Green",
 IIF(((Fields!DriveLetter.Value = "C:") AND (Fields!Database_Name.Value = "master" OR Fields!Database_Name.Value = "model" OR Fields!Database_Name.Value = "msdb" 
                                                                                 OR Fields!Database_Name.Value = "tempdb")), "Lime", "Red" )))

Comment: I copied it into notepad++ i thought it looked ok :P i guess not :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hooks were not set correct:

```
IIF(((Fields!DriveLetter.Value = "F:" OR Fields!DriveLetter.Value = "T:") AND
(Fields!FileType.Value = "MDF" OR Fields!FileType.Value = "NDF")), "Green", 
IIF(((Fields!DriveLetter.Value = "G:" OR Fields!DriveLetter.Value = "U:") AND 
(Fields!FileType.Value = "LDF")), "Green", IIF(((Fields!DriveLetter.Value = "C:") AND 
(Fields!Database_Name.Value = "master" OR Fields!Database_Name.Value = "model" OR 
Fields!Database_Name.Value = "msdb" OR Fields!Database_Name.Value = "tempdb")), "Lime", 
"Red" )))
```